# Dynamic Drop Down List using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i have database schema :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zone_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `zone` (`id`, `zone_name`) VALUES
(1, 'first'),
(2, 'second');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `error` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `errorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `error_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `error` (`id`, `errorID`, `error_name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'test1'),
(2, 1, 'test2'),
(3, 1, 'test3'),
(4, 1, 'test4'),
(5, 2, 'test5');
```

MyController.php

```
class myController extends Controller {

    public function zoneMethod()
    {
        $zone = DB::table('zone')->get();

         return View::make('myview', ['zone' =>'zone']);

    }

    public function errorMethod($id)
    {
        $error = DB::table('error')->where('errorID', $id)->get();
        return View::make('thisview', ['error' => 'error']);
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('myroute','myController@zoneMethod');
Route::get('my/{id}','myController@errorMethod');
```

And i have

View.php

```
<label for="zones">Zone</label>
<select name="parent_zone" id="parent_zone">

    @foreach($zone as $zones)
    <option value="{{ $zones->id }}">{{ $zones->zone_name }}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>
<br/><br/>

<label for="errors">Error</label>
<select name="sub_error" id="sub_error">

        @foreach($error as $errors)
         <option value="{{ $errors->id }}">{{ $errors->error_name }}</option>
        @endforeach

<br/><br/>
</select>
</div>
```

I have error - "Undefined variable: zone ...", help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Edit code in controller:

```
return View::make('myview', ['zone' => $zone]);
```

instead of

```
return View::make('myview', ['zone' =>'zone']);
```